# How to pass ASSERTION in TestNG?

Tags: java, testng

In the if condition I want to pass the assertion(means TRUE) and in the else condition I want to make it fail(means FALSE). How it could be possible in TestNG (using assertion)??

```
if (counter2 == counter+8)
{
    // Some code here to pass the assertion.
}
else
{
    Assert.fail("Assertion failed due to less no of videos as expected");
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with Selenium. Please specify whatever your testing framework is and what your language is (looks like Java or JavaScript to me). I guess you don't need `if-else`, but something like `if (counter2 != counter+8) {Assert.Fail("blah");}`

Comment: @Yi Zeng I am using java as the language and TESTNG framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if (counter2 != counter+8) {Assert.Fail("blah");}

This is the best solution i have found.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like below:

```
if (counter2 == counter + 8) {
    try {
        Assert.assertEquals(expected, actual);
        System.out.println("Pass message");
    } catch (Throwable assertionError) {
        System.out.println("Fail message");
    }
}
```

Does this help?

Comment: This is the best Solution :: if (counter2 != counter+8) {Assert.Fail("blah");}

Comment: Nice to know that you got the the best suited solution for your need.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just put your code that should pass the assertion after the assertion?

```java
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

@Test
public void myTest() {
    // ...
    assertEquals(counter + 8, counter2);
    // Some code here after passing the assertion.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to look at different assertion libraries. JUnit and TestNG have their own assertions. You can also take a look at hamcrest (https://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/)